# Changing peso to baht, in Thailand or the Philippines?

Tags: money, exchange

I'm changing Philippine pesos to Thai baht. Where can I get more favourable exchange rate, in general? In Thailand, or the Philippines?

Comment: There is high variance also inside a country. In general: touristy place can have many places with bad exchange rate. Your bank could give you better deals. Foreign exchange can give you smaller notes (but you need already some for Taxi in airport). So it is a difficult question to answer exactly, but I would say: it doesn't change too much (if you are careful to check best rates)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi In my experience, bank rates in SE Asia are poor.  In KL, the small money changers in KL Sentral tend to give good rates, although I'm not familiar with the peso specifically.